# how to convert if else statement to ternary operators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

how can I rewrite the following javascript code to ES6 version:

```
if(allUser[currentUser]['email']==email){
        if(allUser[currentUser]['password']==password){
            isUserFound = true
            passwordCorrect = true 
            break
        } else {
            isUserFound = true
            passwordCorrect = false
            break
        }
    } else {
        isUserFound = false
    }
```

Comment: What is an "ES6 version"? Ternary operators have existed in the language since the beginning.

Comment: `(foo['email'] == email && foo['password'] == password) ? isUserFound, passwordCorrect = true : isUserFound, passwordCorrect = false;`

Comment: Also, just a minor offf-topic note: please don't develop the habit of omitting the semicolon `;` from the end of lines, it only leads to trouble.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for pointing out typo.
To help OP, ternary syntax: `if_evaluation_block ? true_condition_block_OR_another_ternary_block_here : else_condition_block_OR_another_ternary_block_here`

Comment: @Rikin, can you write that code for me, please.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a bad idea, your code is more readable with `if`/`else`. You could simplify to:

```
isUserFound = allUser[currentUser]['email'] === email;
passwordCorrect = isUserFound && allUser[currentUser]['password'] == password
```

In case you didn't know, `break` also has no effect on an `if`, only `for`, `while` and `switch`.

Comment: I assume the `break` _is_ in a loop. It says `currentUser` and `isUserFound`, implying the OP’s looping over many users to find a particular one. Perhaps, this could be written with `find` which is probably what the OP means with “ES6”.